# How to save a hard disk partion while clean install windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, reinstall

I am using windows media creation tool for upgrading my pc but because i m insider it tells me "your current installation is in the wrong dir or you try to upgrade older version". I want to save my partition which has personal files is that any way to save it during a clean install

**Edit -

hey I am upgrading from windows media creation tool so it only allows me the option of nothing so it deletes all files from c drive or all partitions**

Comment: Shrink the existing partition, create a new partition, move files to new partition

Answer (score -1):

You can't transfer your files when doing a clean install. Copy the files you want to keep onto an external hard drive or similar and then, if you want to preserve the partition itself, just format it before reinstalling

Comment: hey I am upgrading from windows media creation tool so it only allows me the option of nothing so it deletes all files from c drive or all partitions

Comment: Windows installer will only touch the system partition

Comment: @Ramhound man are you sure my files are very important, cuz it says all files apps and setting will removed

Comment: You need to move the files of your system **partition** otherwise they will be deleted.  Read both of my comments carefully.  I am 1000% sure that a secondary partition will not be touched by the Windows installer